# Akka, Camel and ActiveMQ: throttling consumers

Tags: scala, apache-camel, activemq-classic, akka

I've got a very basic skeleton Scala application (with Akka, Camel and ActiveMQ) where I want to publish onto an ActiveMQ queue as quickly as possible, but then only consume from that queue at a particular rate (eg. 1 per second).

Here's some code to illustrate that:

**MyProducer.scala**

```
class Producer extends Actor with Producer with Oneway {
  def endpointUri = "activemq:myqueue"
}
```

**MyConsumer.scala**

```
class MyConsumer extends Actor with Consumer {

  def endpointUri = "activemq:myqueue"

  def receive = {
    case msg: CamelMessage => println("Ping!")
  }
}
```

In my main method, I then have all the boilerplate to set up Camel and get it talking to ActiveMQ, and then I have:

```
// Start the consumer
val consumer = system.actorOf(Props[MyConsumer])
val producer = system.actorOf(Props[MyProducer])

// Imagine I call this line 100+ times
producer ! "message"
```

How can I make it so that `MyProducer` sends things to ActiveMQ as quickly as possible (ie. no throttling) whilst making sure that `MyConsumer` only reads a message every *x* seconds? I'd like each message to stay on the ActiveMQ queue until the last possible moment (ie. when it's read by `MyConsumer`).

So far, I've managed to use a `TimerBasedThrottler` to consume at a certain rate, but this still consumes all of the messages in one big go.

Apologies if I've missed something along the way, I'm relatively new to Akka/Camel.

Comment: You shouldn't create a new producer every time.  Just create one and store the ActorRef.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, good spot - I'm now only instantiating it once.

Answer (score 0):

How many consumers comprise "MyConsumer"?

a) If it were only one, then it is unclear why a simple sleep between reading/consuming messages would not work.

If there are multiple consumers, which behavior are you requiring:

- each consumer is throttled to the specified consumption rate. In that case each Consumer thread still behaves as mentioned in a)
- the overall pool of consumers is throttled to the consumption rate.  In that case a central Throttler would need to retain the inter-message delay and block each consumer until the required delay were met . There would be the complexity of managing when there were backlogs - to allow "catch-up". You probably get the drift here.

It may be you were looking for something else /more specific in this question. If so then please elaborate.

Comment: There's only a single `MyConsumer` - so yes, adding a `Thread.sleep` works. However, it still appears that all the messages get de-queued from ActiveMQ immediately, whereas I'd like them to be de-queued at a rate of 1 per second.